# Как получить данные API запроса Python

Tags: python, бот

пишу бота для tf2.tm подскажите как получить значение переменной id (свой ключ замазал)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

myurl = "https://tf2.tm/api/v2/my-inventory/?key=*****"

zapros = requests.get(myurl)
print(zapros.content)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какой вам нужно узнать тег? в ответе я вижу много id

Comment: в первую очередь - не скидывайте скриншоты, никогда, только текст! (если уж скидываете скриншоты, всегда копируйте весь текст оттуда)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возникший вопрос говорит о вашем незнании основ, поскольку довольно прост. Ознакомьтесь с базовыми примерами, статьями, уроками. В данном случае, потребуется [json](https://python-scripts.com/json), [list](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html), [requests](https://pythonru.com/biblioteki/kratkoe-rukovodstvo-po-biblioteke-python-requests).

Согласно [документации](https://tf2.tm/docs-v2), запрос `my-inventory` возвращает ответ в виде json. Следовательно его нужно парсить для получения эквивалента в объектах python. И затем читать данные.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "14933635912",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Получить json вы можете так

```
requests.get(url).json()
```

Добраться до значения id так

```
data['items'][0]['id']
```